# How to grep data of a new line when capturing a keyword?

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep, scripting

I have a file which contains below sample line having a common keyword P00001121 in each line.

```
[H00,P00001121] CHANNEL__OPEN:TCP_ADDRESS='10.32.130.202' TCP_PORT='80'"
[H00,P00001121] COMMS_QUEUING:RECV='01/08/2019 14:33:45.064410' QUEUE_TIME='00000.000' TO_DEV='
[H00,P00001121] FROM_EXCHANGE:HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n
Content-Length: 878\r\n
Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2019 04:33:45 GMT\r\n
\r\n
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : CLIENTID =>
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : TRANSACTIONID => 20190801143344970"
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : KEY_TYPE => SERVICEID
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : ORDERSOURCESYSTEM =>
```

I want to capture all the line of the keyword (P00001121) and also the following few lines below keyword which has \r\n in it (there may be 1 line with \r\n or 10 lines with \r\n in the following lines). Now all the lines in the file having keyword has those following line with \r\n in it. I am ok to use any command, be it grep, awk, cut etc whichever works.

```
[Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n
Content-Length: 878\r\n
Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2019 04:33:45 GMT\r\n
\r\n
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>]
```

Comment: Please post the sample output as text delimited text (separated as new lines ) as the one you have given is not line delimited and is being read as one long line. However in the meantime I will provide an answer by delimiting the one you have given and it should get you going.

Comment: Interesting, when you go to inspect the element in devtools your text is nicely formatted. I wonder what caused unixexchange to lose its mind (and why parts of my answer got printed in red)

Comment: Why are you editing your question with a new user? If you lost the credentials of your original user, look into the faq on how to regain access. It's not a good idea to create a new user then. Thank you.

Comment: Some `grep(1)` implementations (e.g. the GNU one, universal on Linux) allow you to ask for some lines before/after the matching one.

Comment: If you want all lines with `P00001121` and all following lines with `\r\n`, all the lines of your example, except for the `<soap:` line should get printed. Is that correct? The second sniplet seems to show the lines that *don't*  contain `P00001121`, but that is different from what you describe, so why are you showing this part without explanation?

Answer (score 0):

After having inspected the OPs text input (see comment), I was able to get the original nicely formatted text which looks like this:

```
[H00,P00001121] CHANNEL__OPEN:TCP_ADDRESS='10.32.130.202' TCP_PORT='80'"
[H00,P00001121] COMMS_QUEUING:RECV='01/08/2019 14:33:45.064410' QUEUE_TIME='00000.000' TO_DEV='
[H00,P00001121] FROM_EXCHANGE:HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n
Content-Length: 878\r\n
Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2019 04:33:45 GMT\r\n
\r\n

[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : CLIENTID =&gt;
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : TRANSACTIONID =&gt; 20190801143344970"
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : KEY_TYPE =&gt; SERVICEID
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : ORDERSOURCESYSTEM =&gt;
```

Assuming the text resembles something like this (I'll update my answer after the provided text is edited-updated)

You can do  (assume that your text input is named `ex1`

```
cat ex1 | grep -P '\\r\\n|P00001121'
```

and you will get:

```
[H00,P00001121] CHANNEL__OPEN:TCP_ADDRESS='10.32.130.202' TCP_PORT='80'"
[H00,P00001121] COMMS_QUEUING:RECV='01/08/2019 14:33:45.064410' QUEUE_TIME='00000.000' TO_DEV='
[H00,P00001121] FROM_EXCHANGE:HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n
Content-Length: 878\r\n
Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2019 04:33:45 GMT\r\n
\r\n
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : CLIENTID =&gt;
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : TRANSACTIONID =&gt; 20190801143344970"
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : KEY_TYPE =&gt; SERVICEID
[H00,P00001121] CONTEXT=PARAMETER : ORDERSOURCESYSTEM =&gt;
```

However, something tells me you might be looking for something else, like getting the selected line text only , or perhaps some additional grouping, if so please update your question.

Comment: You don't need to use `cat`. `grep` already sends the result to standard output just like `awk`, `sed`, and `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tricks I've used with output similar to yours.

#### 1. Filter out matching lines with `grep`

Notice that the lines you want do not include the string `P00001121`. Knowing this you can have `grep` show all the lines where this string is absent:

#### Example

```
$ grep -v P00001121 afile
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n
Content-Length: 878\r\n
Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2019 04:33:45 GMT\r\n
\r\n
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
```

#### 2. Select a range of lines with `sed`

You can use `sed` to select all the lines between 2 patterns. Here I use `sed -n` to suppress `sed`'s default behavior of printing each line of input. Next we tell `sed` to match any lines between 2 patterns and then and then print them (`/p`).

```
$ sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' afile
```

#### Example

```
$ sed -n '/^.*Server/,/^\\r\\n/p' afile
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8\r\n
Content-Length: 878\r\n
Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2019 04:33:45 GMT\r\n
\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `grep`, `awk`, or `sed`.

```
grep -v H00 file.txt
```

That `-v` switch prints out all of the lines not containing that string.

```
sed -n '/Server/,/soap/p' file.txt
```

That prints the lines between the ones containing those strings.

```
awk '/Server/','/soap/' file.txt
```

That prints out the lines between the ones containing those strings just like above but uses `awk`.

They all give your desired result.